# Select multiple values as object in SPARQL pattern

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

In SPARQL we can do something like this

```
select * where {
    ?s   (_:prop1 | _:prop2)  "some_val" .
    ...
    #use ?s in other patterns
    ?s    ?o    ?p .
}
```

Is it possible to do the same for the object part of the pattern? And what are some workarounds of this in case it is not possible?

For example:

```
select * where {
    ?s   _:prop ("v1" | "v2") .
    ...
    #use ?s in other patterns
    ?s    ?o    ?p .
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  The simplest and pure SPARQL 1.0 method is to use `UNION` e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  { ?s _:prop "v1" } UNION { ?s _:prop "v2" }

  # Use ?s in other patterns
}
```

This is probably the simplest method but if you need multiple constraints on `?s` this can quickly get unwieldy.

Second method is to use the `IN` function in a `FILTER` clause, this requires a SPARQL 1.1 implementation e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  ?s _:prop ?value .
  FILTER(?value IN ("v1", "v2"))

  # Use ?s in other patterns
}
```

Problem here is that using `IN` can perform very poorly if you have many alternatives or a lot of data that may be matched by `?s _:prop ?value`

*Aside* - Many optimisers will actually expand this second method into the first method under the hood.

Third method is to use the `VALUES` clause which again requires a SPARQL 1.1 implementation:

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  VALUES (?value) { ( "v1" ) ( "v2 " ) }
  ?s _:prop ?value .

  # Use ?s in other patterns
}
```

This is likely the best option since it scales to many alternatives better (depending on your SPARQL implementation) and is maybe the nicest to read and write.

Answer (score 5):

This works well:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
    VALUES ?value
    {
       "value1"
       "value2"
       "etc"
    }

    ?s ?p ?value
}
```